# Keep getting the error For input string:"" in my code

Tags: java

I keep getting this error on my code. I think its to do with my parseInt() command but im not sure. Im trying to create a stack of integers that come from a user input string such as "PUSH 5" and just extract the 5 from the string to push into the stack.

```
import java.util.*;

public class lab6
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = sc.nextInt();
        
        lab6stack theStack = new lab6stack(size);
        String [] ar = new String [size];
        
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            ar[i] = sc.next();
            
            if(ar[i].charAt(1) == 'U')
            {
                String sub = ar[i].substring(4);
                int num = Integer.parseInt(sub);
                
                theStack.push(num); 
            }
            
            else if(ar[i].charAt(1) == 'O')
            {
                theStack.pop();
            }
        }
        
        while (!theStack.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println(theStack.pop());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If your goal is to read entire text `PUSH 5` as one string then you need to use `nextLine()` for that. Just be careful if you are using it after `next()`, `nextInt()` or other `nextABC()` methods since they don't consume line separators which causes `nextLine()` to see them immediately which is interpreted as user pressign enter without providing any data. Solution and longer discussion is at ["Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045).

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, `sc.next()` only returns `"PUSH"`, not `"PUSH 5"`. In my opinion, @Pshemo's solution works just fine, but you said that it is not how you want to do it. In that case, you can replace your `sc.next()` with `sc.nextLine()` to get `"PUSH 5"`. That way, you can keep the rest of your code the same.

Hope this is what you want!

Comment: appreciate the answer but after i changed it to nextLine() i get an out of bounds error from the line "ar[i].charAt(1) == 'U'"

Comment: Another day, another person is suffering from ["Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045)).

Answer (score 0):

You're referring to the space between `PUSH` and your number in this line:

```java
String sub = ar[i].substring(4);
```

As substrings also start counting on zero, your number should be parsed when using `substring(5);` here instead.
Here is an example with indexes:

```
"P"=0 ; "U"=1 ; "S"=2 ; "H"=3 ; " "=4 ; "3"=5
```

Comment: If i use 5 then it says out of bounds

Comment: That is because `next()` doesn't return `"PUSH 5"` but only `"PUSH"`.

Comment: i changed it to nextLine() but now im getting an out of bounds error from the line "ar[i].charAt(1) == 'U'"

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not checking the length of the string before grabbing the character.

here:

```
if(ar[i].charAt(1) == 'U')
```

and here:

```
else if(ar[i].charAt(1) == 'O')
```

Check with `ar[i].length() >= 1`. For example:

```
if(ar[i].length() >= 1 && ar[i].charAt(1) == 'U')
```

You will also need to apply the other two fixes addressed in the other answers.

Use `sc.nextLine()` when reading the input and use `substring(5)` in the "PUSH" if case.