# Keep getting "String index out of range: 1" error

Tags: java

This code is meant to receive a String input such as "PUSH 5" and take the 5 from the string turn it into an int and do the push command. However I keep getting the string index out of range error on the line "char s = ar[i].charAt(1);" Any ideas?

```
import java.util.*;

public class lab6
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = sc.nextInt();
        
        lab6stack theStack = new lab6stack(size);
        String [] ar = new String [size];
        
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            ar[i] = sc.nextLine();
            char s = ar[i].charAt(1);
            
            if(s == 'U')
            {
                int num = Integer.parseInt(ar[i].substring(5));
                
                theStack.push(num); 
            }
            
            else if(s == 'O')
            {
                theStack.pop();
            }
        }
        
        while (!theStack.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println(theStack.pop());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your string is less than 2 characters long.

Comment: the string im entering is "PUSH 5"

Comment: This was already answered [in your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64900313/keep-getting-the-error-for-input-string-in-my-code). In addition to that, also note that you are just checking for one character. The user could input anything with U or O as the second character and your code would do the same, even if the user didn't input "PUSH" or "POP". Also, your code fails if input is entered in lower case.

Comment: You read an int from the scanner first, then you read a line. The line you've read from it is empty, for reasons described in the dupe.